# Is this question really duplicate?

Tags: support, specific-question, duplicates

Is [this question asked by me](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23571/wow-a-pong-game-with-the-help-of-ascii-art/23575?noredirect=1#23575) really duplicate?

I think that [the duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10713/pong-in-the-shortest-code/) is not the same as the one I asked.

Answer (score 4):

Two questions do not have to be identical to be considered a duplicate. Your question is similar enough to the other one to count.

The real question to ask is, does a new question add value, compared to questions previously asked?

Comment: But, my question is **ASCII ART** and the other question is not ascii art.

Comment: The job of a moderator is to enforce the decisions of the community, so, I'm going to let the community decide whether ASCII art adds enough value to warrant a separate challenge. :-)